# Subtract 2 Dataframe columns and save in new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 Pandas DataFrames looking like:

df1:

```
 0     1     2     3
 0.001 0.001 0.001 300
 0.002 0.002 0.002 270
   ...
```

df2:

```
 0     1     2     3
 0.001 0.001 0.001 210
 0.002 0.002 0.002 220
   ...
```

As column 0, 1 and 2 are always the same I want to subtrct df1.3 with df2.3.
like:

```
df3 = df1.3 - df2.3
```

It doesn't work, but I think it shows what I want to achieve.

I want df3 to look like:

```
0
90
50
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df3 = df1.3 - df2.3` this should also work, what error you are getting, please print your df3

Comment: Oops, my bad `df[3] = df1[3] - df2[3]` this should work, I almost forgot about its datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pnadas data frame indexes can be text or integer or dates. it depends on how they're created.

If I read in the sample data, then it defaults to text. However, the actual type could be integer.

if the column names are text then this will work

```
df1['3'] - df1['2']
```

if they're integers, then this will work instead

```
df1[3] - df2[2]
```

if you want to get the difference purely on the position of the column within the dataframe, use `iloc`

```
df1.iloc[:,3] - df2.iloc[:, 2]
```

to see the types of the column elements use

```
df1.columns
```

it should output either

```
# 1: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
# 2: Index(['0', '1', '2', '3'], dtype='object')
```

Use the column-selecting technique that is appropriate for your column name type.

Answer (score 1):

Literal `3` is not a valid identifier in Python, hence it cannot be a DataFrame attribute. You need to explicitly access the column, i.e.

```
df3 = df1[3] - df2[3]
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. I always used df1.columnname for Pandas DataFrames and it always worked. This time it didn't.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 df3 = df1['3'] - df2['3']
```

An alternative:

```
 df3 = df1['3'].sub(df2['3'])
```